# Is there a mathematical notation for the expression "all components of a vector"?

Tags: notation

Let's say that you have a vector P with 4 components: A, B, C or D. The components of the vector are not single values but vectors themselves. If all components of a vector are distributed with a standard normal distribution, one would usually write this down like this:

A ~ N(0,1) 
B ~ N(0,1) 
C ~ N(0,1) 
D ~ N(0,1)

However, I was wondering if it is anyhow possible to write in a single line that all components of the vector P are distributed normally.

Comment: I would say that, for instance, $A_i\sim N(0,1)$ for all $i$ (in runes, $\forall i, A_i\sim N(0,1)$), since the distribution of the coordinates of a vector does not determine the random vector (whereas $A\sim N(0,1)$ would suggest that the distribution of the random vector $A$ is being specified).

Comment: The notation $A\sim N(0,1)$ means that $A$ is a real valued standard normally distributed random variable. Not a vector. @J.Doe : If you want to express the four lines in a single line I agree with Sassatelli Giulio: $A_i\sim N(0,1)\forall i.$ But only this far.